# Pull data from database to tables in Django framework

Tags: django, database, python-3.x, django-forms, html-table

How to pull data from database to HTML tables in django?

I already have my model built.

```
class device:
    track_no=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dev_type=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dev_name=models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

I want to make a form in which I can populate a table with the data of "device" table. Also I want an extra field in the table as a checkbox in front of every row.
Please mention all the files which required.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://$SITEURL$/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://$SITEURL$/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you a very good Django app called "**Django Tables2"**

[Django Tables Documentation](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html)

*After you have installed it, you need to add **django_tables2** to your installed apps*

They are pretty easy to use, you need to create a file **tables.py** in the same folder as your settings.py models.py...

Inside this **tables.py** file you have to add a new table using one of your models, example:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from models import *

class DeviceTable(tables.Table):
    # row_id used to have each ID in a first hidden row
    row_id = tables.columns.TemplateColumn(attrs={'cell': {'style':'display:none'}}, template_code=u'<span id="row_id_{{ record.id }}">', orderable=False, verbose_name=u'Row ID')    
    name = tables.columns.TemplateColumn(template_code=u'{{ record.dev_name }}', orderable=True, verbose_name=u'Device Name'))
    checkbox = tables.columns.TemplateColumn(template_code=u'<input type="checkbox" >',orderable=False, verbose_name=u'Checkbox')

    class Meta:
        model = Device
        attrs = {'class': 'myClass'} #Add table classes here
        fields = ('row_id', 'name', 'track_no', 'dev_type','checkbox')
        sequence = fields
        order_by = ('name', )
```

You can customize the fields or add new ones, the documentation is pretty well explained. Once you have the table created you need to load the table in your view:

```
from django_tables2 import RequestConfig
from tables import DeviceTable

def yourView(request, ...):

    # ... Your actual code ...

    # We get the object list
    device_list = Device.objects.all()

    # We pass the object list to the table
    table = DeviceTable(device_list)

    # RequestConfig is used to automatically add pagination to the table
    RequestConfig(request, paginate={"per_page": 10}).configure(table)

    return render_to_response('your_template.html', {'table': table, }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And to render this table in your template you need to load the template_tag for rendering the table:

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
  # ... Your other code ...
  <div class="col-md-12">
    {% render_table table %}
  </div>
```